# php login on other website and see if data is correct

Tags: php, html, curl

I am making a website and came across quite a problem.

Small explanation (with fake adresses),

I have a website, www.website1.com, with tons of good coded things ;). Now you can login on this website, but using www.website2.com. So when you login you see the www.website1.com login page, but you are loggin in on www.website2.com.

Now I have researched, and found out about cURL. But there is my problem.
Not only I want people to login on www.website2.com. I also what to save username, emailadress for use on www.website1.com.

Is this possible within HTML/PHP/cURL? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow. I hope it is alright :D.

EDIT:
I have made something myself using cURL but there are some problems with it.
index.php (website1)

```
<?php
$username="user1"; 
$password="password1"; 
$url="http://localhost/AAWebsite/test/action.php"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "email=".$username."&password=".$password."&submit=submit"; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

login.php (website2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
            <p>You are logged in as <?=$_SESSION['username']?></p>
            <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
<form method='post' action='action.php'>
    Email Address: <input type='text' name='email'>
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'>
    <button name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

action.php (website2)

```
<?php
    $user = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if($user == ''){
        header("Location: index.php?error=email_missing");
    };

    if($pass == ''){
        header("Location: index.php?error=password_missing");
    };


    $result = filter_var( $user, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
    if(!$result == $user){
        header("Location: index.php?error=email");

    } else { 


        header("Location: index.php"); }
?>
```

zindex.php (website2)

```
index site
```

Now the problem is, that you get logged in from index.php. But you get stuck on action.php. What could be a fix for this?

Comment: you'll have to write codes to redirect to www.website2.com on successfull login in www.website1.com..

Comment: Are you going to steal passwords from users using fake/duplicate website?

Comment: You need to implement SSO. Interdomain redirection doesn't work for authentication.

Comment: @Justinas no? both websites are mine.......

Comment: maybe for login data and user data use a seperate database so that you have 1 "general" personal info database and make a cronjob to distrubute that data to 2 other "site" databases so that you have teh data there as well?

Comment: I tested a code on localhost, where cUrl is enabled, and it didn't work. I just dont get a result. Nothing. What could be the solution to this? @Nick

Comment: Bring up this post because I really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right I would make something like this using PHP:

I going to use some *EXAMPLE CODE*

login php:

```
<form action="http://www.domain1.com/test/redirect.php"  method="post">
Login Details:</br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$name?>" /></br>
<input type="text" password="password" value="<?=$password?>" /></br>
<button name="Submit" value="Submit">login</button>
</form>
```

and in the redirect page put the login function from site1 login in site1, redirect to site2 login validation page to login on site2 and get back to site1 if you like or stay in site2 that is up to you

on redirect I would send data using GET to site2
(It is a good idea to encrypt data first)

redirect.php

```
if(!empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $user= query("SELECT * FROM ".USERS." WHERE user = '".$_POST['user']."' AND password= '".$_POST['password']."'");
    if($user->num_rows == 1){
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $user->fetch_assoc();
        header("Location: http://www.site2.com/getsite1.php?user=$_POST['user']&&password=$_POST['password']");
    }
    else{
        unset($_SESSION['uid']);
        header("Location: index.php?msg=Invalid Username or Password.");
    }
}
```

on getsite1.php in site2 I'll have some similar code to login on site2 and then redirect back to site1 or stay in site2

Not the best solution but is what I would use in the mid time until I could find a more permanent one

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding this. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood you. What you want is people in www.website1.com to login in on both websites at once? (www.website1.com and www.website2.com)

Comment: Yes, well kinda, the login form is on www.website1.com and the info has to be checked on www.website2.com. But they do not necessarily have to be logged in on www.website2.com. It doesnt really matter tho.

Comment: So I go to www.website1.com and fill in the username and password but the dadabase with usernames and passwords is in www.website2.com ? What database are you using? (Mysql, SQL, no-SQL, Mongo, TxT files?) and with www.website1.com and www.website2.com you mean they are different hosting accounts? (Hostigator1, Hostigator2 ?? )

Comment: First question, Yes. Seconds question, Mysql, Third question yes. different hosting accounts

Comment: Why dont just point www.website1.com login page to "www.website2.com" database? or you have 2 databases (1 for each site) and you want members from www.website1.com be able to login in www.website2.com and viceversa? I got you right?

Comment: I want to have users from website2 log in on website1. But the databases cant be pointed towards each other.

Comment: I see how this can be a problem if the code and functions of your sites are different... but lets try a solution

userA from website2 try to login on website1, but userA does not have an account on website1, therefore the login page at website1 will search website1 database and wont be able to find userA in case this returns TRUE website1 will redirect to website2 sending the usarA info through using  $_GET

Comment: and search the credentials of userA on website2 database once the info is retrieved website2 will redirect back to website1 with another $_GET sending the info of userA, then website1 will create an account for userA on website1 automatically so next time user4 log in on website1 it will have an account

as for password changing on one website or the other you can use a similar process to update both websites passwords for that particular user

Does that work for you?